# How can I allow sub-services to use concrete types, without having an ever-growing type argument list on the primary service?

Tags: design, c#, object-oriented-design

***NOTE**: I believe I have a bit of an X/Y problem here, so please, bare with me. Also, I have trouble explaining things sometimes, so feel free to ask me to elaborate, and I will improve anything I can about my question to make it clearer.*

---

I have a system in which I have a central `service` that calls a `processor` to perform some work such as fetching and processing data.

The central service, in my design, should have no knowledge of the concrete types that the `processor` is working with, and instead should work with interfaces to ensure that the `processor` is at a minimum, working with data types that meet the requirements for whatever call it's executing.

---

### Example Use Case

Let's say I need to fetch entity locations and process them, excluding the specific implementation details, I know that I need to define the following:

- An interface describing the data model.
- An interface defining methods to fetch and process the aforementioned data model.

So the code would look something like this:

```
public interface IEntityLocation {
    object Id { get; set; }
    double? Latitude { get; set; }
    double? Longitude { get; set; }
}
public interface IEntityLocationService {
    bool TryFetchEntityLocations(out IEnumerable<IEntityLocation> locations);
    void ProcessEntityLocations(IEnumerable<IEntityLocation> locations);
}
```

---

### Explaining the Problem

While the sample code in the use case above would work just fine for implementers, they lose the ability to work with their concrete types. I'd much rather work with generics while enforcing constraints, thus giving the implementer, the ability to work with their concrete type instead:

```
public interface IEntityLocationService<T> where T : IEntityLocation {
    bool TryFetchEntityLocations(out IEnumerable<T> locations);
    void ProcessEntityLocations(IEnumerable<T> locations);
}
```

This would be perfect, except that I have a service provider definition that looks like this:

```
public interface ILocationServiceProvider {
    IEntityLocationService<T1> EntityLocationService { get; }
    ISomethingElseLocationService<T2> SomethingElseLocationService { get; }
    void RecordSomethingAboutLocations(...);
}
```

So the `processor` implements `ILocationServiceProvider` to define how it's location services should function. Essentially, `IEntityLocationService` above is a sub-service of the location service which is why I want to define it in this manner. However, having a type argument for all of these sub-services, is NOT scalable due to the fact that implementers end up with something like this:

```
internal sealed class LocationServiceProvider : ILocationServiceProvider<EntityLocation, SomethingElse, ..., InfinitelyMany>
```

Which probably means there's something wrong with my design, at some level.

---

### Sample of the Service

As asked for in the comments, here is an example of the above in action, to demonstrate what I'm talking about:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

// Create the definitions in the shared assembly:
public interface IEntityLocation {
    object Id { get; set; }
    double? Latitude { get; set; }
    double? Longitude { get; set; }
}
public interface IEntityLocationService {
    bool TryFetchLocations(out IEnumerable<IEntityLocation> locations);
    void ProcessLocations(IEnumerable<IEntityLocation> locations);
}
public interface ILocationServiceProvider {
    IEntityLocationService EntityLocationService { get; }   
}

// Simulate a "processor":
public sealed class EntityLocation : IEntityLocation {
    public object Id { get; set; }
    public double? Latitude { get; set; }
    public double? Longitude { get; set; }
}
public sealed class EntityLocationService : IEntityLocationService {
    public bool TryFetchLocations(out IEnumerable<IEntityLocation> locations) {
        // Simulate fetching locations.
        var result = new List<EntityLocation>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var location = new EntityLocation();
            location.Id = i;
            result.Add(location);
        }
        
        locations = result;
        return true;
    }
    public void ProcessLocations(IEnumerable<IEntityLocation> locations) {
        // Simulate processing.
        foreach (var location in locations)
            Console.WriteLine(location.Id);
    }
}
public sealed class LocationServiceProvider : ILocationServiceProvider {
    public IEntityLocationService EntityLocationService => new EntityLocationService();
}

// Simulate the "service":
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Simulate loading the "processor" through reflection:
        ILocationServiceProvider locationService = new LocationServiceProvider();
        
        // Some underlying work common to all "processor"s has been done.
        // Simulate the need to fetch locations:
        locationService.EntityLocationService.TryFetchLocations(out IEnumerable<IEntityLocation> locations);
        
        // Some more underlying work has been done.
        // Simulate the need to process locations:
        locationService.EntityLocationService.ProcessLocations(locations);
    }
}
```

---

How can I allow the implementers of the sub-services described above, use their concrete types, without having an ever-growing type argument list on my quote-unquote service provider?

Comment: My initial reaction of that maybe you do not have something as generic as you think you do. Is the interface really that useful?

Comment: Can you include more information about what this service class looks like and how it interacts with the processors?

Comment: @GregBurghardt the service itself is more of a collection of classes and methods as singular application, to automate a lot of the common work that the processors have to do, leaving the processors to focus on doing the primary work. The processors are loaded at runtime via reflection, and then the service determines when and how the appropriate providers, if supported in the processor, should be utilized. I've updated my question with a very simple example of a processor being executed from a console application with comments. More than happy to elaborate more if needed.

Comment: @GregBurghardt with regards to your comment about not being as generic as I think I am, I think that's probably accurate. I'm trying to get to a state where the processors can use their concrete types instead of my interfaces, so long as their concrete types implement my interfaces. I'm thinking that, in order to accomplish it, I'll need to move the `sub-service` up to an individual service instead, so instead of `locationService.EntityLocationService.TryFetch` it would be `entityLocationService.TryFetch` which probably fits better with single responsibility.

Comment: I think you've correctly identified that this is an X/Y problem. But you still haven't told us what X is. What problem are you trying to solve with this design?

Comment: _"How can I allow sub-services to use concrete types"_ **Cui bono?** There are three main actors in this play: (a) the top-level consumer of the provider (b) the provider implementation (c) the specific locationservice implementation (= processor). Which of these needs access to concrete types because only knowing the interface would hamper their work? This part is unclear to me. It seems like you're targeting (a) here; but then I'm wondering why you've even bothered to use interfaces if the consumer needs to know the concrete type anyway.